# Find Percentile of a soql query

Tags: soql, division

I Want to find a 97thPercentile discount in soql query and i want to do the division in the query too
i tried the following code

SELECT percentile_disc(0.50) within group (order by NegoiatedDiscount__c) percent,sum(ListPrice__C)/sum(TargetPrice) listTarget
FROM Opp_Segement__c
GROUP BY Market_Segments__c

but it is not working properly ...thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOQL is not the same as SQL, so I'm afraid that what you're trying to do is impossible (with SOQL alone, at least).

SOQL can't perform math operations like division (only what we're given through the aggregate functions, i.e. SUM(), MAX(), AVG(), COUNT(), etc...), doesn't have a `percentile_disc()` function nor a way to define/use our own functions, and doesn't have a `WITHIN GROUP` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro,i tried the following way as they mentioned but i could not get it as i expected              https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_fn_agg_pd.htm

Comment: @Dinesh ah, are you trying to work with SAQL (Salesforce Analytics Query Language, used by the Einstein Analytics feature) instead of SOQL (Salesforce Object Query Language)? That makes a _huge_ difference. If you are working with SAQL, you should edit your question (and the tags) to reflect that. We can't read your mind or see what you see. We can only rely on the words you say and the details you give us. Being very detailed is important on this site.